# Solving a Matrix-Differential equation with e.g. ode45

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-calculus

Solving a Matrix-Differential equation with e.g. `ode45` derived from some matrix-valued function $E(t)$ where $E$ is a $m\times m$ Matrix, I get a ODE $$\dot E=-G(E)+Re( \langle G(E),E \rangle )E$$ with $\langle,\rangle$ the standard scalar product and $G(E)$ as well a $m\times m $ matrix. 
$E \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ with Frobeniusnorm of 1 and $E$ a real multiple of $G(E)$ along Solutions of the ODE. The ODE arises out of a revised paper, I have to base my bachelors thesis on, so the existence of a solution is given.

My idea was reshaping the $m\times m$ Matrices to a $1\times m^2$ vector, but I didn't get this to run.
As I have never seen any examples, where all parts of the ODE are matrices I would appreciate some help. :)

The idea behind the paper is, given a square matrix $A$ with some eigenvalues with positive real part you want to find a perturbationmatrix $E$, such that $A+\varepsilon E$ has no eigenvalue with positive real part. $(\varepsilon>0)$
$\lambda_i(t)$ for $i=1,...,m$ denotes one of the simple eigenvalues of $A+\varepsilon E(t)$, $x_i ,y_i$ left and right eigenvectors. While deducing the ODE $G(E)$ is given as $G(E)=\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{Re(\lambda_i)}{x_i^*y_i}x_iy_i^*$, with $^*$the complex conjugate. Solving the ODE gives the wanted perturbation.

Mostly my implementation errors are dimensionality issues,I understand using matlabs ode45 for equations of type $\dot{x}=Ax$, with $A$ some square matrix. But with $E$ not being a vector, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Has your matrix complex entries? The real part for the scalar products seems to imply that. Is $G$ bounded, linearly bounded, globally Lipschitz or has a different growth characterization? Depending on that the solution might only exist on a very small interval.

Comment: How sure are you about the additions? If $\|E\|_F=⟨E,E⟩_F=1$ has to be preserved under the dynamic, would the equation not be $$\dot E=G(E)-Re(⟨G(E),E⟩_F)E,$$ so that $\frac12\frac{d}{dt}\|E\|_F^2=Re(⟨\dot E,E⟩_F)=0$? Is "E a real multiple of G(E)" (or vice verse) not too strong a restriction? Would it then not be easier to replace $G(E)=c(E)\,E$ with a real scalar valued function $c$?

Comment: Still does not make sense, since now the right side cancels to zero if the multiple is real. On the other hand, if it were purely imaginary, $G(E)=i\,c(E)\,E$, then you would not need the correction term. However, in that case the dynamic is just a phase change in $E$, $E(t)=e^{i\,a(t)}\,E(0)$.

Comment: Your idea is a sensible one, it should work with an integrator that works on complex-valued states. Please report what exactly the implementation problems were.

Comment: Dear LutzL, may I ask if you could provide me with some further reading?